# What are the simplest quantum 1D spin chain models which aren't integrable?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lattice-model, integrable-systems

What are the simplest quantum 1D spin chain models which aren't integrable? Are there any generic criteria for telling whether or not a given quantum 1D spin chain model is integrable?

Comment: Take a Heisenberg spin chain (nearest-neighbor coupling) and add next-nearest-neighbor coupling. I think this breaks the integrability.

Comment: Not necessarily, for example, the Inozemzev chain, which is a long-range chain is integrable http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.3985v3.pdf